# firebase signInWithCustomToken not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use firebase authenticate my users with a custom token i generate

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {
                    System.out.println("canceled");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("failure");
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        System.out.println("complete");
}});
```

token is a valid authentication token i get from my server
This method is called on a `WorkerThread`

but no message is printed on console

what might be happening?

===========UPDATE==========
I tested and it work fine on API lvl 27
but it doens't work on API 16
according to firebase page, fibase requires minimum api 9

Answer (score -1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Make sure you have a valid token. You can paste it into https://jwt.io/ and compare it to a valid token or check the elements that are required as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). The token has to be signed with a private key of the same Firebase project that you are trying to connect to. You can get the private key from the Firebase Console / Project Settings / Service Accounts
2. In the OnFailureListener, print out the exception message, e.g. e.getMessage().

   ```
   addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
         Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
       }
   ```

Comment: i dont know if you read the description but i already checked the token is valid, and i already have listeners to every possible situation and nothing is printed on console

Comment: check my answer in 2. You may get more detail by printing the exception message.